# Can't bind to 'lowercase' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm fairly new to Ionic 3 and Angular and I've come across something that has be a bit confused, as it looks like I'm doing all the right things, but am getting the error in the title.

I have a directive I'm trying to apply to a field that will force the entry to be lowercase:

```
import {Directive, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[lowercase]',
    host: {
        '[value]': 'lowercase',
        '(input)': 'format($event.target.value)'
    }
})
export class LowercaseDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input() lowercase: string;
    @Output() lowercaseChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.lowercase = this.lowercase || '';
        this.format(this.lowercase);
    }

    format(value) {
        value = value.toLowerCase();
        this.lowercaseChange.next(value);
    }
}
```

I've added the DirectivesModule to my main app controller:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LowercaseDirective } from './lowercase/lowercase';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [LowercaseDirective],
    imports: [],
    exports: [LowercaseDirective]
})
export class DirectivesModule {}
```

But when I try to add it to my login page, like this:

```
<ion-content padding class="master">

    <div class="error-message" *ngIf="error !== ''">
        {{error}}
    </div>
    <ion-list>
      <form #loginForm="ngForm" 
            (ngSubmit)="userLogin(loginForm)">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label for="name" stacked>username</ion-label>
          <ion-input 
            required
            ngModel 
            [(lowercase)]="login"
            name="login" 
            type="text" 
            id="login" 
            #login="ngModel"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <div class="warnings" *ngIf="login.touched && !login.valid">username is required!</div>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label for="password" stacked>password</ion-label>
            <ion-input 
              required
              ngModel
              #password="ngModel"
              name="password" 
              type="password" 
              id="password" ></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <div class="warnings" *ngIf="password.touched && !password.valid">password is required!</div>
          <button  
            class="button"
            [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" 
            ion-button color="primary" 
            round 
            full 
            type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </ion-list>

<a class="go-to-reset" (click)="goToResetPassword()">Whoops. I forgot my login...</a>

</ion-content>
```

The imports on my login.component.ts looks like this:

```
import { AuthenticationProvider } from './../../providers/authentication/authentication';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  error = '';


  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    private auth: AuthenticationProvider) {
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log('Member Info: ', this.auth.memberInfo());
  }
...
```

I get the following error:

**Can't bind to 'lowercase' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'**

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you import the `DirectivesModule` in the module where `LoginPage` is declared ?

Comment: I didn't. I imported it into the main app module so it should be global. Isn't that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Declarations (Components, Directives, Pipes) are only available in the modules where they are imported. Providers (Services) are available in the global application, importing a service multiple times will result in resetting the service by a new instance.

You can find an explanation of [Why is a service provided in a feature module visible everywhere?](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#why-is-a-service-provided-in-a-feature-module-visible-everywhere) on the angular.io :

> This is by design. Extensibility through NgModule imports is a primary
>   goal of the NgModule system. Merging NgModule providers into the
>   application injector makes it easy for a module library to enrich the
>   entire application with new services. By adding the HttpClientModule
>   once, every application component can make HTTP requests.

For a better understanding, [I recommand this article by Cyrille Tuzi](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/understanding-angular-modules-ngmodule-and-their-scopes-81e4ed6f7407).